# でようか slang for で良いか?

Tags: usage, colloquial-language, slang, word-usage

This is the sentence I heard in an anime.

コーヒーでようか　or コーヒーでよか.

I definitely did not mishear it for yoi 良い. Is this some slang for yoi? If so, which is the correct one? Stress or no vowel stress.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't コーヒー入{い}れようか?

Comment: Feel free to hear it yourself. 15:53 and again at 16:00 https://www11.animeultima.eu/a/witch-hunter-robin_242406/episode-15_940631-sub

Answer (score 6):

The sentence is

> コーヒーいれようか 
>   *Shall I make some coffee?*

（入れ-る or 淹れ-る can be used according to your taste)

「いれ」 part is pronounced weak in the original audio, which would explain why you heard it as 「で」．